# Should answers be framed in response to the Title or the description?

Tags: discussion, answers

The question [Does activating a scroll require satisfying the spell's verbal and somatic components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168339/does-activating-a-scroll-require-satisfying-the-spells-verbal-and-somatic-compo/168341#168341) frames the question in the Title such that "Yes" would mean the exact opposite regarding the question in the body.

Is it better for clarity to respond "Yes" to the title question or "No" to the question in the description?

The question [Should we be answering the question, or the question posed in the description?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/should-we-be-answering-the-question-or-the-question-posed-in-the-description) is relevant but directed towards general vs specific questions

Comment: I've pointed this back to an earlier question tackling the same problem--edit them to bring them in line so that they're not opposite questions.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the most important part of any question and answer is the body. So the body of the question should give the problem, and the body of the answer should give a clear answer to it.

On the other hand, good titles are useful. They establish a frame, making the body easier to understand (because you know where it is going, or what the key is). The problem is that the question comes with two different frames for the same question. I see two major ways to solve this (non-exhaustive and non-exclusive):

- Use non-Yes/No titles. Give the key factual statement as your title/lead in instead. It accomplishes the same result of establishing a frame for your answer, without risking ambiguity from depending on the question's frame. Eg. "Scrolls require V/S components", "The Wizard is prevented from activating the scroll"
- Fix the question. Posts on SE are editable, and as long as you are only changeing the Yes/No-frame of the question and not the underlying one, there is no problem. There's no hard rule for which one best or authoritative. Use the one that is the best summary, flows the best and/or is replied to by existing answers (so you're not forcing them to change). If you're unsure which would be best, post a comment suggesting to unify the title and body so they're more in line. That's what comments are for.